# Generated column doesn't work for z/os while it is ok in LUW

Tags: db2-zos

The following DDL is valid for LUW.

```
CREATE TABLE three_a(
    c1   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    c2   INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS c1 + 10
)
```

But it is NOT valid for z/OS:

Any idea how to implement `GENERATED ALWAYS` to use it like computed columns in SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not implemented in the Z/OS version. You can find the allowable various options for "default" in the SQL manual under the "create table" SQL statement. There is an option to define a fieldproc on a column but it will not be (and do) what you want (more on it in the administration guide).

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE Table1 (
    c1 INT NOT NULL,
    TS INT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
);

ROWID type (instead of INT) is defined without the "AS IDENTITY"

Comment: I don't want an IDENTITY column, I want a generated column that depends on  other data.

Comment: What do you mean by "depends on other data"?

Comment: I've revised the question. Please check it again.

Answer (score 0):

Use a trigger for that. Look at SQL manual for the "create trigger" command.
If you need it only while inserting rows then "before insert trigger" would suffice.
If you want it for changes as well then you'll need an "update trigger" also.

Comment: The problem is, a really basic requirement implemented by most DBMS’es is not available for db2 z/os. It is even implemented by the LUW version. Instead of trigger, I can change my all insert statements as well, but that doesn’t answer the question.